# Find string in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I find/match a string in an array?

**How can I search within this?**

[image]

If for example the likes[3].id was "99999" and that was what I wanted to search for... How could I do this??

I tried this:

```
var likes = response.data
jQuery.inArray(99999, likes)
```

But without any luck...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you also tried `jQuery.inArray("99999", likes)`

Comment: `likes` appears to be a `json` object not an array.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inArray` will only search the top level objects in your array, as you need to find the value of a property on an object you'd need to do something like (not tested) -

```
var found = false;
var indexFoundAt = -1;
jQuery.each(likes,function(index, value) {
   if (value.id == "99999") {
     found = true;
     indexFoundAt = index;
     return false;  
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you need to find a string in an array of objects within the `id` property of each object.

So here's what I suggest

```
function findId(id_needed)
{
  var found = 0;
  var arrayResult = []
  var likes = [] //your array of objects ofcaurse should be filled some how

  for(var i = 0;i<likes.length;i++)
  {
    if(likes[i].id==id_needed)
    {
      arrayResult[arrayResult.length]=likes[i];
      found +=1;
    }
  }
  return {Found : ((found>0)?(true):(false )),Result : arrayResult}
}
```

this function will return an object with 2 properties

1. Found - [true/false]
2. Result - array of objects with needed ids