# JQuery JSON-within-JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Consider the following nested JSON:

```javascript
{
  "state": [
    "Tennessee"
  ], 
  "more_data": [
    {
      "letters": {
        "last": "e", 
        "first": "T"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to print the JSON in JavaScript in a flat manner, i.e. root_key=value:

```javascript
  var my_json_str = "{\"state\":[\"Tennessee\"],\"more_data\":[{\"letters\":{\"first\":\"T\",\"last\":\"e\"}}]}";
  console.log(my_json_str);
  my_json = jQuery.parseJSON(my_json_str);
  for (var key in my_json) {
      console.log(key,":",my_json[key]);
  }
```

But I get (FireBug console):

```javascript
state : ["Tennessee"]
more_data : [Object { letters={...}}]
```

Instead of the desired:

```javascript
state:["Tennessee"]
more_data:[{"letters":{"first":"T","last":"e"}}]
```

How do I fix this?

**Solution - following your answers:**

http://jsfiddle.net/wrAUB/

```
var jsonStr = "{\"state\":[\"Tennessee\"],\"more_data\":[{\"letters\":{\"first\":\"T\",\"last\":\"e\"}}]}";

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
for (key in jsonObj) {
    console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(jsonObj[key]));
}
​
```

Which gives:

```
state:"Tennessee"
more_data:{"letters":{"first":"T","last":"e"}}
```

Comment: **You don't have to fix anything, there is nothing wrong** (well, unless you really want to print it in a different way, but why?). It's just how Firebug displays nested objects. You can work with the data as expected. Btw, you don't have JSON within JSON. You just have JSON (JSON within JSON would be something like `{"foo": "{\"bar\": 42}"}`, i.e. a string containing JSON).

Comment: This is a printing problem, not a parsing problem.

Comment: Reminds me of the old infomercials...: "Sorry, Tennessee."

Comment: I believe you can use the method suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992429/537913) for flattening your object

Comment: Just a side note, but if you are fetching the JSON with ajax, you can use `$.getJSON()` and this will eliminate the need to use `$.parseJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you would want to call JSON.stringify on the values of the key-value pairs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to turn the objects you're iterating over back into JSON strings:

```
var jsonStr = "{\"state\":[\"Tennessee\"],\"more_data\":[{\"letters\":{\"first\":\"T\",\"last\":\"e\"}}]}";

​var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
for (key in jsonObj) {
    console.log(key+':'+JSON.stringify(jsonObj[key]));
}
```

See it in action on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hEvFr/

​