# plotting JSON data using jqPlot

Tags: jquery, json, jqplot

I'm trying to plot some `JSON` Data using the `jqPlot` library within an HTML 5 app powered by jqMobile. I'm placing the following code within the 'body' of the html page. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get the JSON data from server
    $.getJSON("myspecialurl", function(data) {
        success: function(data) {
            plotData(data);
        }
    });
    // plot the data
    function plotData(data) {
        ds = [];
        $(data).find('latitude').each(function() {
            ds.push([$(this).attr('answer'), parseInt($(this).attr('count'))]);
        });
        $.jqplot('chart1', [ds], {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer
            },
            legend: {
                show: true
            }
        });
    }
}    
</script>
```

**Edit:** New Plot Method

```
function plotData( data ) {
 // ds = [];
 // $(data).find('latitude').each( function() {
 //   ds.push( [ $(this).attr('answer'), parseInt( $(this).attr('count') ) ] );
 // } );
var array = data.contacts;


$.jqplot('chart1', array[0].latitude, {
seriesDefaults:{
   renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer
},
legend: {show:true}
 });
}
```

Comment: At the fist glance it appears to be OK. How does the `JSON` looks like before your operations. Do you enter the `plotData()`?

Comment: the console is throwing this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: I also get this error regarding data Exception: ReferenceError: data is not defined]

Comment: OK but at which point/step in your code? Plus show the JSON.

Comment: http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=? is json url

Comment: @Boro between succes:function ( data ) and plotData( data ); it says that there is an Unexpected token (

Comment: Put `console.log("OI");` inside the method called on `success` and let me know if it gets called. It is to big to see if there are some problems but if you will enter the `success` it would mean that `jQuery` parsed it all right.

Answer (score 1):

Of coarse there is a problem and the computer is again right. This is how your code should look like. You were defining success as if you were using `ajax` method, with `getJSON` success is passed as the 2nd parameter.

```
$.getJSON("myspecialurl", function(data) {
    plotData(data);
});
```

**EDIT**
I spot also that you are not closing the `ready` function appropriately. It should be `});` rather than just `}`.

Comment: ahhh, ok yup that cleared up that error, however the console is now throwing this error Uncaught No plot target specified  but yet I am specifying a plot...

Comment: At which line is the reference exception thrown?

Comment: at line 1881 in jquery.jqplot.js file which makes me think that this code is fine, except that I can't access my data. when I try to access a certain piece of data it is held within an index, like 0,1,2,3. When I try to do data.contacts.0.name it does not like the number 0, even though I need that to access the JSON data bit. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Please see the **EDIT**.  I hope it wasn't me who removed the `ready` method's closing.

Comment: ok so I have edited my question so that it shows my lastest plot method, which is still showing "Uncaught No Plot target specified" error in console, however I now know that my data is there (I've been able to log in to the console). Am I not understanding something about jqPlot?

Comment: AS it goes to `find` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992429/613495  AS it goes to format of Donut chart http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php  Thus, something like this `[[['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]]]` should go it the place of `array[0].latitude`