# How to extract values from geojson efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a `geojson` file of the following structure:

```
var areas = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "name": "a", "count": "854" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.271687552328165, 29.359549285088008 ], [ 13.272222904657671, 29.357697459147403 ], [ 13.272586765837973, 29.35566049412985 ], [ 13.273062097784726, 29.354438105832578 ], [ 13.272652418199639, 29.360795108476978 ], [ 13.271320041078822, 29.360700647951568 ], [ 13.271687552328165, 29.359549285088008 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "properties": { "name": "b", "count": "254"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.277038163109875, 29.358442424220023 ], [ 13.276782949188294, 29.358122923383512 ], [ 13.275290999273452, 29.358508600578681 ], [ 13.274634727185679, 29.358485484466968 ], [ 13.282581930993208, 29.358635779719847 ], [ 13.278334024184868, 29.359814295404375 ], [ 13.277038163109875, 29.358442424220023 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": {"name": "c", "count": "385"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.279484097462499, 29.349831113628788 ], [ 13.27792879702741, 29.349728966688758 ], [ 13.276089401418951, 29.349901260351807 ], [ 13.275677565886326, 29.349951087700632 ], [ 13.279484097462499, 29.349831113628788 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 3, "properties": { "name": "d", "count": "243"}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 13.290520299215724, 29.352306689134622 ], [ 13.289722088408338, 29.351802774685929 ], [ 13.289065241087885, 29.352101541350635 ], [ 13.28785814146197, 29.351114667998772 ],  [ 13.290520299215724, 29.352306689134622 ] ] ] } }

]
}
```

Normally, to convert this data into an array I would create a loop to run through the appropriate variable storing this value in an array. However, I don't know if this is the best approach. Is there a way of pulling out all of the values for `id` into an array so that I would end up with:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

I'm happy to use any external library to do this either - I'm mainly curious if there is a more efficient way than my current approach.

Comment: What's your current approach?

Comment: I normally create a loop and cycle through the array -  I was wondering if I could pull out the variables directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely desperate to give something else a go, you could try [underscore's map](http://underscorejs.org/#map). The code would look something like this:

```
_.map(areas.features, function (item) { return item.id });
```

This will call the inner function on each item in features, and return an array containing each result.

I don't think there's anything too radical you can do here - ultimately, pulling values out of nested objects and arrays can't be dumbed down all too much.

Answer (score 1):

Not my code but there is a post on here regarding getting values from json quite efficiently.

refer to post 
[use jQuery's find() on JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object)

Answer from User Box9 is probably the best way

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Upvoted this answer in regards to this code block as well because it's about the best way I've found to pull out values

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
    var arr = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < areas.features.length; i++){
        arr.push(areas.features[i].id)
    }
```

To get a certain `id` value directly you can do something like this:

```
areas.features[0].id
```

which in this case would be `0`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RC6cL/)**

Comment: You may also cache the features length, this may help in some browsers