# Searching JSON object with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, search

I'm new to JQuery and have to search a json object with jquery. the json structure is as follows:

```
[
    ["12345","Mary Smith","789 Main Street","Orlando","FL","32808"],
    ["33333","James Richards","55 High St","Miami","WV","23412"]
]
```

I want to search the object on the basis of first value i.e. 12345 and return the whole object.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look at this post and I think you will get your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript as:

```
var entry = myJson["12345"];
```

or for Jquery need to write a function (as doesn't work on plain object literals):

function getObjects(obj, key) {

```
var objects = [];
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj[i][0] == key) {  
        return obj;
    }        
  }
 return objects;
}
```

Use like so:

```
getObjects(myJson, '12345');
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/tDYrw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var queryJson = [["12345","Mary Smith","789 Main Street","Orlando","FL","32808"],["33333","James Richards","55 High St","Miami","WV","23412"]];

alert(queryJson[0]);
// will return a string array

alert(queryJson[0][0]);
// will return a string value "12345"

alert(queryJson[1][0]);
// will return a string value "33333"
```

I think I helped you. bye