# Finding a particular value in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, search, object

I humbly ask for assistance.  I am working on a project where I need to set up a search to find all instances, inside an Object where a particular value equals whatever term the user is searching for.  I found the following code:

```
    function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object) (to make sure proper credit is given),which works great, but I am looking for some help on expanding the functionality of this code to include the ability to search for more than one element at a time, and also, on the return, display other values in the same objects being returned.  As an example, the returns, using the above code, are simply [Object]:

What I was hoping to do was to append the [>Object] with another variable value from the Object, perhaps the ID or Description, both of which are part of the returned results.  So, the desired results would be  something like "Object: ID=b01" or "Object: Desc = This is Maple", something that will allow my users to quickly see which one of the results they need to look at.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: look into using jsonpath

Comment: So if they can search for more than one element at a time would the object be added to the objects array if it matched all elements or any elements?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.  If they have multiple elements in the search, it would be an AND instead of OR, so all.

Comment: @Alnitak The data source is not a JSON object, so I would have to convert it before I could use JSONPath.  If that ultimately is what needs to be don, then I will go down that road, but I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: @AndrewR jsonpath works on the parsed JSON data, which happens to be native JS object structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I have changed the function to look through a tree like object and be able to pick out the objects that contain all of the supplied `key-value` pairs. In addition, it allows you to specify that you want to output extra parameters on the objects that match. (like the `id` and `description`)

Here is the code and example
http://jsfiddle.net/hjhQz/

Comment: Thanks Tom!  I will give it a test when I get back in tomorow.

Comment: One more question, if I wanted only the `id` and `description` returned instead of the entire original object, how would I change the  function? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hjhQz/1/ basically the only change is this line `var out = {};`