# How to loop through JSON file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am trying loop through the following JSON file below:

```
 {
     "statements": [{
         "subject": "A"
     }, {
         "predicate": "B"
     }, {
         "object": "C"
     }, {
         "subject": "D"
     }, {
         "predicate": "E"
     }, {
         "object": "F"
     }]
 }
```

As you can see, there are two subjects, two predicates and two objects. I would like to get, for instance, the value `"predicate":"E"`. How can I do this using jQuery or D3 Javascript library. My code below retrieves the first subject `"subject":"A"`.

```
$.each(data.statements[0], function(i, v){
console.log(v.uriString);
});
```

or in D3 (I do not know how to do this in D3):

```
d3.json("folder/sample.json", function(error, graph) 
{  // Code is here for getting data from JSON file }
```

Could anyone please help me loop through the JSON file above and retrieve some particular data either with jQuery or D3 Javascript. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `statements[1].predicate`

Comment: I tried this one but it I did not see any outputs. Any idea, please?

Comment: `statements[1].predicate` would only work if he already knows the index of the item he needs. This will return the predicate value of the second object in the statements array. Also he asked for the one with predicate "E", so that would mean he has to use: `statements[4].predicate`.

Comment: Have a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(data.statements).each(function (i) {
    var d = data.statements[i];
    $.each(d, function (k, v) { //get key and value of object
        $("body").append("<p>"+k + ":" + v+"</p>");
    });
})
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hNLwd/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code returns the first item is beacuse you selected it with `data.statments[0]` and afterwards loop over that one item.

With jQuery you can use the grep-method like this:

```
var arrayWithItem = jQuery.grep(data.statements, function( obj ) {
  return obj.predicate == "E";
});
```

You can read more about the grep-method [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

With D3js I'm not sure, I guess you have to loop through it with an if-statement.