# get the number of times a key:value pair occurs in json

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json with key value pairs and i am trying to know how many times that exact match of that key value pairs occurs in that json  file

This is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "yes"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "yes"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "yes"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"},{"programmer":"yes","married": "no", "does_java": "no"}];

//get the number of times a key:value pair occurs in json

/**
I am trying to know the number of times a specific key:value pair occurs in this json.
*/
$.each(data,function(k,v){
if(v['does_java'] === 'yes'){
console.log($(data).find(v['does_java'] === 'yes').length);
//expecting 3,but displays 0
}
});
});
```

The key value `does_java:yes` appears 3 times but in my case it displays zero.How should i go about fixing this?.

Comment: Jquery `find` doesn't work the way you think it does, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4992383/1592398)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
...

var javaDo = 0;
$.each(data,function(k,v){
    if(v['does_java'] === 'yes'){
        javaDo++;
    }
});

console.log(javaDo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/UYbMH/18/)

```
 keyarr = []
$.each(data,function(k,v){

if(v['does_java'] === 'yes'){
keyarr.push(v['does_java']);
}
});

    alert(keyarr.length)
```