# find value pair in json object using key element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

With reference to question posted here [use jQuery's find() on JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object) 
I have json object in which i'd like to search value of the element if i passed respective key element to it

Json:

```
{"RESPONSE":{"@xmlns":"","CODE":"0","SECODE":"0","TXNID":"17527","LASTBALANCE":"-12078.8","SURCHARGE":"2","CUSTOMERDETAILS":{"NAME":"Mr.ABC"}}}
```

I want to retrieve value `Mr.ABC` when i passed `Name` as a key to my function

Code:

```
console.log(getObjects(ContextObj, 'Name'));

function getObjects(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (i == key) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

It gives output now as

```
[ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {"RESPONSE":{"@xmlns":"","CODE":"0","SECODE":"0","TXNID":"17527","LASTBALANCE":"-12078.8","SURCHARGE":"2","CUSTOMERDETAILS":{"NAME":"Mr.ABC"}}};
function find_value(key, inner_key) {
    var value = "";
    $.each(data.RESPONSE, function (i, k) {
        console.log(i, key, i == key)
        if (i == key) {
            value = k;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (inner_key) {
        if (value[inner_key]) {
            value = value[inner_key];
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Calling function:**

```
find_value("LASTBALANCE");
find_value("CUSTOMERDETAILS", "NAME");
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/56p2r7cs/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your code recursive for nested json keys like,

```
var s={"RESPONSE":{"@xmlns":"","CODE":"0","SECODE":"0","TXNID":"17527","LASTBALANCE":"-12078.8","SURCHARGE":"2","CUSTOMERDETAILS":{"NAME":"Mr.ABC"}}};
console.log(getObjects(s, 'NAME'));
console.log(getObjects(s, 'LASTBALANCE'));

function getObjects(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[i] == 'object'){
            return getObjects(obj[i], key); // if it is an object then find the key recursively.
        }
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if (i == key) {
            return obj[key];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/paxg89q0/2/)**