# How can I get a find an object in an array by a property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array returned from a php script.

```
$data =  [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "created_at": "2015-01-02 15:17:29",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-02 15:17:29",
        "name": "Minecraft",
        "description": "",
        "location": "ideaLab",
        "cost": "20.00",
        "min_age": "7",
        "max_age": null,
        "start_date": "2014-11-06",
        "end_date": "2014-12-11",
        "start_time": "16:30:00",
        "end_time": "17:30:00",
        "registration_start_date": "2014-10-28",
        "registration_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "program_id": "1",
        "max_attendees": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "created_at": "2015-01-02 15:17:29",
        "updated_at": "2015-01-02 15:17:29",
        "name": "Mini Makers",
        "description": "",
        "location": "ideaLab",
        "cost": "18.00",
        "min_age": "9",
        "max_age": "7",
        "start_date": "2014-11-04",
        "end_date": "2014-12-09",
        "start_time": "16:30:00",
        "end_time": "17:30:00",
        "registration_start_date": "2014-10-28",
        "registration_end_date": "0000-00-00",
        "program_id": "2",
        "max_attendees": "20"
    }
];
```

How do I select the object by `id`? something like the SQL equivalent of  `$obj = select * where id=$id` if that makes sense.

Comment: Traverse the array? Btw is is only JSON as long as it is a string. After you parse it is a mere JavaScript object.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7026711/1303429

Comment: just put them all into a list iterate through them until you find it or use map.

Comment: You can use [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) as a more elegant solution

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a generic function that accepts the `id` as argument and return the object (if the id exists)

```
function getObjectById(id) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $data.length; i++) {
      if ($data[i]['id'] === id) {
         return $data[i];
      }
   }
   return {};
}
```

but if your output it's exactly what you posted and you have not missing `id` in the sequence you could just reduce the body of the function to

```
return (id > 0 && id <= $data.length) ? $data[id - 1] : {}
```

(in this scenario I assume you pass an integer number as `id`)

Comment: The most straight forward answer, but I would probably return `null` if not found

Comment: I would do == instead of === because id is a string and may be used as a number ?

Comment: @Hacketo I just prefer by default strict comparison. as long as the values are all strings and you pass a string as parameter then  `===` is fine

Comment: Is this PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: it's vanillaJS @PraveenKumar

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Your use of `$` in front of the variable name was the confusion. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks my output is as posted. I was not aware that it was missing a id in the sequence. I will see if there is a way to add that to the php output. I used Laravel framework .toJson() function. I would have to ensure that the id of the object will always align to the id inside the object though which I would rather not do.

Comment: @Hacketo thanks == is better for me, it is stored as a number in my database but from my research some databases might output as string so I think it best to be as type agnostic as possible here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a small script like this:

```
function findJSONById(needle, jsonString)
{
  var finalJSON = {};
  $.each(JSON.parseJSON(jsonString), function (key, value) {
    if (value["id"] == needle)
    {
      finalJSON = value;
      return false; // break the loop
    }
  });
  return finalJSON;
}
```

Comment: The `return` does not return from the outer function, though.

Comment: I furthermore added a few keywords.

Comment: Shit! How did I even miss that? `:O` Okay I am drowsy, I need to sleep! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery there is a nice function: [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

It filters input array based on filter function.

```
var objectWithId2 = $.grep(data, function (obj) { 
    return obj.id == 2; 
})[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var filtered = function(data, id) {
  return data.filter(function(items, i) {
    return items.id === id
  })
};

console.log(filtered("1"));
```

Answer (score -2):

You would use :

```
$data[0].id
```

So, to get the object by it's id:

```
$data[$id+1]  //so long as their position in the array is not shuffled.
```

Or, so long as you are using jQuery, something like this should be helpful:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {  console.log(data[i].id); });
```

Comment: This gets the id of each object. OP wants to find the entire object by its id.

Comment: Should be $id - 1 i guess.