# How to search through an array of objects inside a JSON object for a string and return the object that contains it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

### The Problem

The method to search through a JSOn Object that I found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4992429/4206306) works well, however, I need it to return the **"object that contains the matched object, value or pair"** rather than the matched object itself.

### The Code

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
getObjects(obj, key, val);
```

### The Question

How can I augment that to return the **object that contains the matched object/value/pair** instead of just the match itself? (jQuery or JS)

### JSON Sample

- [full JSON jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamandrebulatov/ktc17k9u/)

For example, I need to check if the value "Delivered, Front Door/Porch" of key `Event` (or `Event[#text]`) exists, and if so, I need to find the `EventDate` in that object in which the `Event` was found.

```
{
    "TrackResponse": {
        "TrackInfo": {
            "@attributes": {
                "ID": "9470111699000308312927"
            },
                "GuaranteedDeliveryDate": {
                "#text": "September 9, 2015"
            },
                "TrackSummary": {
                "EventTime": {
                    "#text": "2:06 pm"
                },
                    "EventDate": {
                    "#text": "September 10, 2015"
                },
                    "Event": {
                    "#text": "Delivered, Front Door/Porch"
                },
                ...
            },
                "TrackDetail": [{
                "EventTime": {
                    "#text": "8:07 am"
                },
                ...
            }, ... {
                "EventTime": {},
                ...
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at it from a different angle. You say "the object that contains the match," but in reality, that object *is* the match. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into that.  I am also looking through the answer which was provided as "Duplicate link," and as that answer is pretty long, it's gonna take me a little while to consume and try.  If my question really is duplicate, I will delete it.

Comment: If you feel the linked material does not solve your problem, please let me know and I will remove the duplicate selection.

Comment: @TravisJ, thank you! Apologies if it IS in fact a duplicate, I searched through literally over a dozen similar sounding questions to no avail (though perhaps it's just my ignorance showing). *I'll be back.*

Comment: Nah, it can be hard to find the exact name of the thing you are looking for sometimes. There is nothing wrong with having a "signpost" question which just makes linking more viable. I was just trying to help you solve your problem without reproducing material. But if it does not help, I can reopen it.

Comment: Yeah, posts like these still come up in searches and make it even easier to find the community-accepted answer. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @AndreBulatov - So for your exact situation, are you only looking for the one date? For example, the linked material could be used like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vnxfujgv/

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you for the awesome code -- helped me further understand my problem.  The JSON USPS returns to me has an object I need to search (*here your code works perfect, for TrackSummary obj*), but if the query is not matched, I then need to search the array of objects, `TrackDetail`.  I only need this function for this JSON and I basically need to find the corresponding EventDate of the matched object of objects.   I've tried to adapt your code into a "Full Search" here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamandrebulatov/fx0Lsbn0/4/ but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working with the following function:

```
function ContainsKeyValue(obj, key, value) {
    if (obj[key] === value) return true;
    for (all in obj) {
        if (obj[all] != null && obj[all][key] === value) {
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof obj[all] == "object" && obj[all] != null) {
            var found = ContainsKeyValue(obj[all], key, value);
            if (found == true) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
for (var eventType in historyDates) {
    for (var i = 0; i < trackingDetails.length; i++) {
        var detail = trackingDetails[i];
        if (ContainsKeyValue(detail, "#text", eventType)) {
            historyDates[eventType] = detail.EventDate["#text"];
        }
    }
}
```