# Search array by variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have got a problem by searching JavaScript array by variable.

```
var category = $(this).data('ord');
```

Data category contains an array i.e: `{"name":"John", "subsite":"example.com"}`

I would like to search this array by variable called `filter` that contains an filter.

I was trying to do `var search = jQuery.inArray( filter, ord );` but this return `undefined`

I also was trying to do it in this way: `var ord = $(this).data('ord').category;` this is not working too.

When i'm trying to do `var category = JSON.parse($(this).data('ord'));`

Console returns an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
var order = JSON.parse($(this).data('ord'));`

Arrow is pointing on `JSON` pharse.

Can somebody explain to me how to do that correctly?

EDIT:

`var ord = parseInt($(this).data('ord')[filter]);`

Following code is looking for index by variable.

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4992429/4730201

Comment: `I would like to search this array` - you can't, because it's not an array

Comment: `data-ord='{"all": "43","artist": "44","composer": "43"}'`

Why this is not an array

Comment: `Arrow is pointing on JSON pharse` - because you are trying to JSON.parse something that is not JSON ... JSON is a string notation - you have a javascript object, so no need to parse it as a JSON string

Comment: so what should i do? i stuck in this problem

Comment: `data-ord='{"all": "43","artist": "44","composer": "43"}'` - to the right of the = you have a JSON string, which would need to be parsed - however, what are you trying to say with that piece of incorrect "code"

Comment: `so what should i do?` - step 1, understand what an Array is, and that you don't have one, step 2, write code to search through an objects properties, step 3 - profit

Comment: i resolved my problem. Edit in question above

Comment: Thanks for your tips. It is better than ready to go code