# Query and get a unique list of values from geoJSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, geojson

So I have a geoJSON object that looks like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": 
              [{"type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                               "site_name": "Active Reef (Active Sound)", 
                               "ccamlr_id": "48.1",
                                "site_id": "ACTI",
                                "model": "penguinmap.site"}, 
                "id": "ACTI",
                 "geometry": {
                               "type": "Point",
                                "coordinates": [-2435551.681071794, 1650542.7689355933]
                 }}, 
                {"type": "Feature",
                 "properties": {
                                "site_name": "Acuna Island",
                                "ccamlr_id": "48.2",
                                "site_id": "ACUN",
                                 "model": "penguinmap.site"},
                 "id": "ACUN",
                 "geometry": {
                               "type": "Point",
                               "coordinates": [-2279902.543759384, 2308975.9799890867]}}, 
            .......}]
```

I'm looking for a function that queries this by a property.  More specifically, something like:

```
getObjects(geoJsonObj,"ccamlr_id", ['48.1', '48.2'])
```

or something like that, where the query could be on multiple objects.  In R the equivalent would be something like `filter(geJsonObj, 'ccamlr_id' %in% c('48.1', '48.2')`.  I'm looking for a jQuery or Javascript analog.

This link:
[use jQuery's find() on JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992383/use-jquerys-find-on-json-object) was pretty close, but it only works on a single value. I.E.,
`getObjects(geoJsonObj, 'ccamlr_id', '48.1');`
but I'd like to get it so it works on multiple values of the key.

The getObjects function is:

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

huh - well that ended up being easier than expected... a small tweak to the above function:

```
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && $.inArray(obj[key], val) > -1) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```